# Does ExternalInterface support dot notation access to a function owned by an object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Does ExtenalInterface.call support dot access to functions?

I'm trying to write a wrapper class and not have all my functions on the window document so I've put them in my own class MyClass.MyFunction.

But does that work with external interface? Will this work:

```
var result:Object = ExtenalInterface.call("MyClass.MyFunction", "hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call())

> The alphanumeric name of the function to call in the container. Using a non-alphanumeric function name causes a runtime error (error 2155). You can use a try..catch block to handle the error.

You'll need a dispatcher function to refer things to your class:

```
function dispatcher() {
    var name = arguments[0];
    var func = MyClass[name];

    func.apply(null, arguments);
    //You may also wish to consider slicing the array to remove the function name before calling the function
}
```

And use it like this from AS3:

```
var result:Object = ExtenalInterface.call("dispatcher", "MyFunction", "hello");
```

Comment: Thanks I think I wasn't clear in my question. Sorry. But I think I can this solves another issue I was having. I'll post what I was describing and what I found in an answer. +1 and thanks.